# Is there a more efficient computer algebra system to solve the system of nonlinear equations in N-R method or other numerical methods?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, computer-algebra

Consider the *system* of infinite series
\begin{align}
&F=x+\frac{y^{3^2}}{3}+\frac{x^{3^5}}{3^2}+\frac{y^{3^7}}{3^3}+\frac{x^{3^{10}}}{3^4}+\frac{y^{3^{12}}}{3^5}+\cdots=0
\\
&G=y+\frac{x^{3^3}}{3}+\frac{y^{3^5}}{3^2}+\frac{x^{3^{8}}}{3^3}+\frac{y^{3^{10}}}{3^4}+\frac{y^{3^{13}}}{3^5}+\cdots=0.
\end{align}

I want to approximate its zeros using Newton-Raphson process/ any other method.

Since the above system consists of infinite series, we don't have
technique unless we truncate the system. I am considering the
following truncated system
\begin{align}
&F(x,y)=x+\frac{y^{3^2}}{3}+\frac{x^{3^5}}{3^2}+\frac{y^{3^7}}{3^3}+\frac{x^{3^{10}}}{3^4}=0
\\
&G(x,y)=y+\frac{x^{3^3}}{3}+\frac{y^{3^5}}{3^2}+\frac{x^{3^{8}}}{3^3}+\frac{y^{3^{10}}}{3^4}=0.
\end{align}

This one I am going to try at first.

---

Now in my [previous
post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4438130/can-you-please-help-me-whether-n-r-method-or-other-methods-converges),
I have asked to solve the following system
\begin{align}
&f(x,y)=x+\frac{y^{2^2}}{2}+\frac{x^{2^5}}{2^2}+\frac{y^{2^7}}{2^3}=0 \\
&g(x,y)=y+\frac{x^{2^3}}{2}+\frac{y^{2^5}}{2^2}+\frac{x^{2^8}}{2^3}=0.
\end{align}
The Sage code, given by the use @dan_fulea, was

```
IR = RealField(150)
var('x,y');

f = x + y^4/2 + x^32/4 + y^128/8
g = y + x^4/2 + y^32/4 + x^256/8

a, b = IR(-1), IR(-1)
J = matrix(2, 2, [diff(f, x), diff(f, y), diff(g, x), diff(g, y)])
v = vector(IR, 2, [IR(a), IR(b)])

for k in range(9):
    a, b = v[0], v[1]
    fv, gv = f.subs({x : a, y : b}), g.subs({x : a, y : b})
    print(f'x{k} = {a}\ny{k} = {b}')
    print(f'f(x{k}, y{k}) = {fv}\ng(x{k}, y{k}) = {gv}\n')
    v = v - J.subs({x : a, y : b}).inverse() * vector(IR, 2, [fv, gv])
```

Using the initial guess $(-1,-1)$, the N-R process converges at $8$th
iteration as follows:

```
y0 = -1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
f(x0, y0) = -0.12500000000000000000000000000000000000000000
g(x0, y0) = -0.12500000000000000000000000000000000000000000

x1 = -1.0024422735346358792184724689165186500888099
y1 = -1.0059946714031971580817051509769094138543517
f(x1, y1) = 0.048583106252741437695070286532161290853457141
g(x1, y1) = 0.035005003661522385716279832064793355617823982

x2 = -1.0020504863163137765771033606257451944731308
y2 = -1.0047357187454832971083384658776119569301797
f(x2, y2) = 0.0032718331735723517740747794193782531073714280
g(x2, y2) = 0.0013588050706032233978301227450805778637631180

x3 = -1.0020413711644051490584615403424219543507335
y3 = -1.0046329944054482289164004688385874135513553
f(x3, y3) = 0.000019403097353192714808877039288506402587269048
g(x3, y3) = 2.0763587244920856969768249854671070482986312e-6

x4 = -1.0020414289196482740462473476044443285649078
y4 = -1.0046323504589185162361046727090015558601915
f(x4, y4) = 7.5595118968724701695743900080517263081615759e-10
g(x4, y4) = 8.1922112283336376999011329830106254188700964e-11

x5 = -1.0020414289218795422093499868226092493754357
y5 = -1.0046323504338328451030885177269370761065741
f(x5, y5) = 1.1471443918740692095841154251012109118025975e-18
g(x5, y5) = 1.2374987496689888382750646154304742963132461e-19

x6 = -1.0020414289218795422127464111069351864618923
y6 = -1.0046323504338328450650188283625352002492464
f(x6, y6) = 2.6419634883773767349590310873145265485723181e-36
g(x6, y6) = 2.8548246676615458259051746549294473950928253e-37

x7 = -1.0020414289218795422127464111069351864697057
y7 = -1.0046323504338328450650188283625352001615711
f(x7, y7) = -5.6051938572992682836949183331596645251210478e-45
g(x7, y7) = 1.4538471567369977110833694426632879862032718e-44

x8 = -1.0020414289218795422127464111069351864697057
y8 = -1.0046323504338328450650188283625352001615711
f(x8, y8) = -5.6051938572992682836949183331596645251210478e-45
g(x8, y8) = 1.4538471567369977110833694426632879862032718e-44
```

---

Unfortunately the same code seems to be inefficient to solve the above
truncated system $$F(x,y)=0=G(x,y).$$
It seems this system is associated with higher degrees and that is why the above code is not efficient in this case. The code needs modification.

> Is there a more efficient computer code to solve the system in N-R method or other numerical methods ?

Thanks

Comment: The exponents are so dramatically different from each other that you can probably attack the problem by case analysis: if $|x| < 1$ then solve with only the smallest exponent of $x$ to get a starting value, then add the next exponent of $x$ and repeat. Similarly if $|x| > 1$ start with just the largest exponent. Finally you might want to consider $|x| \approx \pm 1$ by expanding with the substitution $x' = x \mp 1$ and using the same technique. It makes for a lot of cases, but doing it in Sage rather than by hand should be manageable.

Comment: @PeterTaylor, thanks. However I couldn't completely understand your comment. For example, you are talking about only $x$ but it is a two variable system. Can you please turn your comment into a partial answer at least explaining the algorithm which you mentioned above ?

Comment: Yes, having two variables gives 9 cases. On reflection, the tricky case ($|x| \approx |y| \approx 1$) isn't handled well by binomial expansion, but you can exploit the fact that the coefficients are all positive (so the polynomials are monotonically increasing) to use bisection. Since both polynomials are separable (e.g. $F(x,y) = F_x(x) + F_y(y)$ this allows you to plot the locus of $F(x,y) = 0$ by sampling one of the variables and bisecting for the other, and it shouldn't be hard to convince yourself that the only root is $x=y=0$.